# How to obtain a list of all cube's translations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I want to get a list of meta-data translations for our cube (measure groups + dimensions).
I've tried a MDX query in Management Studio:

```
SELECT *
FROM $system.MDSchema_hierarchies
WHERE [CUBE_NAME]  ='DWH OLAP'
```

But can't see there any translation column. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no Translation information at SSAS Management Views. You have to use Microsoft AMO for that, writing a program on .NET. Please find a [code sample](http://sasokoren.com/export-list-of-ssas-objects-and-translations-using-amo-in-net/) doing almost your task, and [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/analysis-management-objects/programming-amo-olap-advanced-objects#Transl) on AMO.